# Daylight Savings Time shift in Timestamp without timezone

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, datetime, dst

I am using hibernate to communicate with a postgresql database for storing data for modelling. In these models, there are time series that are based on time stamps without timezone. Now, when uploading timestamps that were created correctly (in this case for the year 2030), the timestamp for 2030-03-31T02:00 ends up as 2030-03-31T-03:00 in the database in the column that is a timestamp without timezone. I already changed the Database config so that its timezone is UTC, but the problem stays.

The problem seems to be located either in the driver (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql/42.2.5) or in the database. When inserting the timestamp as string, it works. Also this problem is occuring on a local and a remote DB.

Also, hibernate is in Version 5.4.2 (newest) and in my persistence.xml i set the flag:

```
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.time_zone" value="UTC"/>
```

A small test i wrote looks like this:

```
@Test
   public void testTimeShift() {

       EntityManager em = JPAUtil.createEntityManager();


       TimeStep timeStep = new TimeStep();
       LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
       LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2030-03-31T02:00:00");
       timeStep.setTimeStamp(ldt);

       SaveToDB.(timeStep, em);

       em.close();

       EntityManager em2 = JPAUtil.createEntityManager();

       TimeStep timeStep2 = LoadFromDB.getTimeStep(ldt, em2);

       if (timeStep.getTimeStamp() != timeStep2.getTimeStamp()) {
           System.out.println(timeStep.getTimeStamp());
           System.out.println(timeStep2.getTimeStamp());
           throw new EmptyStackException();
       }
   }
```

This code returns the following:

```
2030-03-31T02:00
2030-03-31T03:00

Process finished with exit code -1
```

Comment: If you are using Central European Time (like Europe/Oslo or Europe/Rome), 2030-03-31T02:00 doesn’t exist as far as Java is concerned. It “thinks” that summer time (DST) starts at that point, so the time is 03:00 instead (the rules may be changed before 2030, but Java doesn’t know). I agree that it shouldn’t matter when you use unspecified local time and UTC, but I bet it plays a role nevertheless.

Comment: Yes, I think this is somehow the problem under the hood. But when using the log4j output logger, I can see that hibernate is sending a 02:00 to the driver. So it doesn't seem to be a problem on the java side I think.
Also, I found a similar problem in an old mailing list from 2017, but it was not solved apparently:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/22d79462-2b6d-0276-18f4-f6753e631d1f%40aklaver.com

Comment: Also, I just noticed, that the timestep in the Database is 2030-03-31T01:00. This makes it even stranger. To summarize:
in: 2030-03-31T02:00
there: 2030-03-31T01:00
out: 2030-03-31T03:00

Comment: Another thing: If I put my local System time to UTC, everything works as expected even for the remote Database. For now this workaround is ok, but I still like to know why this is happening

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is to set the type for the timestamp to ZonedTimeData. This can be parsed from and to LocalDateTime for convenience. That way, the test works.

So, in contrast to what is recommended, for a timestep without timezone use:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`TimeStep`")
public class TimeStep {

   @Column(name = "`TimeStamp`")
   private ZonedDateTime TimeStamp;
}
```

Creating timesteps ist then done via

```
LocalDateTime.now(Clock.systemUTC());
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2030-03-31T02:00:00");

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.of(ldt, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
timeStep.setTimeStamp(zonedDateTime);
```